# Do 20th- and 21st-century concerti still follow the expected forms of the 18th and 19th centuries?

Tags: theory, musical-forms, sonata

When looking at opening movements of instrumental concerti in the eighteenth and nineteenth centuries, we see a pretty standard alternation of ritornello (orchestral-focused) and solo sections. These are often (although not always) in a seven-part rotation of RSRSRSR that aligns with the expected sonata-form of the first movement. Occasionally one of these sections will be very short—Mozart's third ritornello section is often only a few measures before it gives way to the third solo section—but the seven-part structure is still obviously present.

But it's relatively rare for me to sense that form in more modern concerti. Even as early as Dvořák's Violin Concerto (1879), I have a hard time tracking the ritornello/solo alternations in a way that aligns with prior practice. When I look at something like the Vaughan Williams Tuba Concerto, it's hard for me to see this ritornello/solo pattern *or* an underlying sense of sonata form in the first movement.

Do opening movements of 20th- and 21st-century concerti still follow the ritornello/solo pattern *or* the expected sonata form of the 18th and 19th centuries? Are there genre-specific patterns for these opening movements that a listener can use to better understand the piece?

Comment: Honestly, I thought even __19th-century__ first movements of concertos no longer follow sonata or ritornello forms.

Comment: Nowadays, and it the 20th century, the conventions from the classical period are seldom followed. You may be able to find them in some concertos (and probably the author wrote them that way for a reason other than imitating Mozart), but the general aesthetics of music have moved on (long long ago).